# ElasticSearch - create query in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have this query I made using sense, I'm breaking my head how to transform it into Java.
I can manage the aggs part, the real pain is the "constant_score"

```
GET /xxxx/yyyy/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                 { "term" : {"userId" : 275}}, 
                 { "range" :{"logDate" : { "gte" : "2016-04-30", "lte" :  "now/d" }}}
                 ]
           }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs" : { 
        "datebucket" : {
            "date_histogram" : { 
              "field" : "logDate",
              "interval": "day", 
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
              "min_doc_count": 0
            },
            "aggs": {
              "info": {
                "filters": {
                  "filters" : [
                  {"term": { "logAction": "sleep" }},
                  {"term": { "logAction": "stop" }}
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had a more simple query I managed to do it like this

```
SearchResponse res = client.prepareSearch("xxxx").setTypes("yyyy")
                                    .setSize(0)                                     
                                    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("userId", 95))
                                    .addAggregation(
                                            AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("date_histogram")
                                            .field("logDate")
                                            .interval(DateHistogramInterval.DAY)
                                            .format("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                            .minDocCount(0)
                                            ).execute().get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution. I hope this will help someone

```
        String query = "{\"constant_score\" : "
                        + "{ \"filter\" : "
                            + "{\"bool\" : "
                                + "{\"must\" : "
                                        + "[{ \"term\" : {\"userId\" : " + userID + "}}, "
                                        + "{ \"range\" :{\"logDate\" : { \"gte\" : \"" + startdate + "\", \"lte\" :  \"" + enddate + "\" }}}]"
                                    + "}"
                                + "}"
                            + "}"
                        + "}";

        SearchResponse res = client.prepareSearch(xxxx).setTypes(yyyy)                  
                .setQuery(query).addAggregation(
                        AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("date_histogram")
                        .field("logDate")
                        .interval(DateHistogramInterval.DAY)
                        .format("dd-MM-yyyy")
                        .minDocCount(0)
                            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.filters("info")
                                    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("logAction", "click"))
                                    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("logAction", "view")))
                        ).setSize(0).execute().get();
```